# How to specify positve and negative values for custom error bars

Tags: excel, office-js, errorbar, excel-web-addins

Thanks the API office.js, I'm displaying a bar chart. Now I want to add custom error bar on each data bar.

The following image shows the result obtained using Excel vba:

[image]

But in the spec of the API office.js, I don't find any information about how to set the positive and negative values for an custom error bars.

On Excel, it can be done using the following graphics options:

[image]

How can I set negative and positive values for an custom error bar with the API office.js ?

Comment: Not sure, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566010/how-to-change-the-error-bar-values-in-a-bar-chart-in-excel-script-lab) _may_ help you get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Office.js doesn't have the API to set custom value for error bars in Excel API set 1.13 and before.